# Easy way to run "explain" on query sets in django

Tags: django, sql-execution-plan

It seems like it should be easy to run "explain" directly off of a queryset in Django, but I don't see anything obvious for how to do it, and "explain" is a difficult thing to search for in the docs.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Well, there seems to be nothing out there except a toolbar so I wrote my own mixin to give me an `explain()` method on my querysets:

```py
from django.db import connections
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

class QuerySetExplainMixin:
    def explain(self):
        cursor = connections[self.db].cursor()
        cursor.execute('explain %s' % str(self.query))
        return cursor.fetchall()

QuerySet.__bases__ += (QuerySetExplainMixin,)
```

Hopefully this is useful to others.

Comment: Please consider opening a ticket for django project. I would love to see this builtin.

Comment: Looks useful, would be even more so with an example of how to actually use it.

Comment: Thank you! This is delicious!

Comment: There is a ticket to add a similar feature to django now : https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28574

Comment: How to use it ?

Comment: Do you include this at the bottom of the file or... where?

Comment: This has been built into Django now https://github.com/django/django/blob/858cfd74e958b63e81657e5a9fc5f751c19e8192/django/db/models/query.py#L772-L773

Answer (score 40):

[`QuerySet.explain()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#explain), available in Django 2.1.0 and above, is now the official way to explain queries.

Answer (score 19):

Just a slight modification to guidoism's answer. This prevents getting a `ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ...` error caused by the parameters not being correctly escaped in the raw query:

```
from django.db import connections
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

class QuerySetExplainMixin:
    def explain(self):
        cursor = connections[self.db].cursor()
        query, params = self.query.sql_with_params()
        cursor.execute('explain %s' % query, params)
        return '\n'.join(r[0] for r in cursor.fetchall())

QuerySet.__bases__ += (QuerySetExplainMixin,)
```

To use, simply invoke explain() at the end of your queryset, e.g.:

```
print SomeModel.objects.filter(...).explain()
```